# ClassNotFoundException in Aspect when using proguard

Tags: java, proguard, aspectj, obfuscation

i have a problem with my aspect class when i obfuscate my codes with proguard.

i have an aspect that detect all methods with @Cacheable annotation.

here is a sample class that contains @Cacheable annotation

```
package com.mycompany.user;

public class User {

    @Cacheable(scope="session", uniqueName="userInfo")
    public UserInfo getUserInfo(Long userId) {
       ...
    }
}
```

and here is my aspect code:

```
@Aspect
public class CacheMethodResultAspect {
    @Around(
            value = "execution(@com.mycompany.cache.Cacheable * *.*(..))",
            argNames = "proceedingJoinPoint,joinPointStaticPart"
    )
    public Object retrieveResultFromCache(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, JoinPoint.StaticPart joinPointStaticPart)
            throws Throwable {

        final CacheScope cacheScope = ((MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(Cacheable.class).scope();
        final CacheConstants uniqueName = ((MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(Cacheable.class).uniqueName();
        final String methodLine = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()
                + "@" + joinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();

                .
                .
                .
    }

}
```

when i log the result of proceedingJoinPoint it returns following line:

```
execution(UserInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.getUserInfo())
```

i expect that it returns this result:

```
execution(UserInfo com.mycompany.user.getUserInfo())
```

it only detects the method name! so i can not fetch @Cacheable annotation for this method!

i do not want to use:

```
-keep class myClassName...
```

aspectj version: 1.6.12

java version: 1.7 update 21

proguard version: 4.9

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would like to help because I know both ProGuard and AspectJ, but your question is so unclear and self-contradictory that I cannot understand your problem. Please edit the question and explain more precisely. If your English is too bad, no problem: let code speak and show us more code.

Comment: sorry. i edited my question :)

Comment: Your ProGuard config is missing. I will look into your problem anyway, but just as a side note: Please use a more up to date version of AspectJ. Version 1.6.12 was released in 2011, you have missed several releases with improvements and bug fixes in between then and today. The current version is 1.8.0.

Comment: i update my aspectj to 1.8.0 but nothing changed :(

Comment: I did not say anything would change after AspectJ upgrade, only that you use outdated libraries. BTW, Java and ProGuard versions are also not up to date. And I would still like to see your ProGuard config. Do you build manually with proguard.conf or with Maven plugin?

Comment: I have the same problem,[this is my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881987/android-aspectj-annotation-after-proguard-doesnt-work),I post all files mybe used, Can you have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this was very tricky, but finally I was able to reproduce the problem with the wrong `MethodSignature` stored in `thisJoinPointStaticPart`. I tried a lot of ProGuard options, but finally I found that `-adaptclassstrings` was the missing one. Obviously AspectJ uses class names encoded in strings - maybe something similar to `Class.forName()`, I did not check the byte code.

The most important part of the ProGuard Maven Plugin configuration is this one:

```xml
<configuration>
    <options>
        <option>-target 1.7</option>
        <option>-adaptclassstrings</option>
        <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }</option>
        <option>-keepattributes *Annotation*</option>
        <option>-keepclassmembernames class * { @de.scrum_master.app.Cacheable *** **(...); }</option>
    </options>
    <libs>
        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
        <!--<lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>-->
    </libs>
</configuration>
```

Because the complete explanation is too big to quote here with full sample code etc., I created a **[GitHub project](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_ProGuard)** for you. Please inspect the code and the Maven settings for ProGuard there. You can just clone the repository and call

```
mvn install
```

I made it very convenient for you, I even included a OneJAR build step, so after the build you can just call

```
java -jar target/aspectj-proguard-1.0-SNAPSHOT.one-jar.jar
```

from the project directory. The output should look like this:

```
User{id=1, info=UserInfo{info='First'}}
User{id=2, info=UserInfo{info='Second'}}
User{id=3, info=UserInfo{info='Third'}}
User{id=4, info=UserInfo{info='Fourth'}}
User{id=5, info=UserInfo{info='Fifth'}}
execution(d de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo(Long))
  Cacheable scope:       session
  Cacheable unique name: userInfo
  Method line:           de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo@27
UserInfo{info='First'}
execution(d de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo(Long))
  Cacheable scope:       session
  Cacheable unique name: userInfo
  Method line:           de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo@27
UserInfo{info='Third'}
execution(d de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo(Long))
  Cacheable scope:       session
  Cacheable unique name: userInfo
  Method line:           de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo@27
UserInfo{info='Fifth'}
execution(d de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo(Long))
  Cacheable scope:       session
  Cacheable unique name: userInfo
  Method line:           de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo@27
null
```

Additional hints:

- I used native AspectJ syntax instead of annotation-based @AspectJ syntax because this is the flavour I feel more comfortable with. But the code is similar enough to your example to be easily convertible. Maybe you need a few more keep clauses for ProGuard for @AspectJ annotations, but that should be trivial.
- The Git repository has two tags, *single_project* (latest commit with one Maven module containing everything) and *multi_project* (older commit with three Maven modules, one for the main application, one for annotations and one for aspects). You can compare both variants if you like.

Enjoy! I hope it solves your problem. `:-)`

**Update:** I forgot to mention how to exactly reproduce the problem: Just remove `<option>-adaptclassstrings</option>`, rebuild and and run the program again:

```
(...)
User{id=5, info=UserInfo{info='Fifth'}}
execution(ClassNotFoundException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.getUserInfo(Long))
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:306)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:159)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.scrum_master.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at de.scrum_master.app.b.getUserInfo(Unknown Source)
        at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```